# how to pass dynamic key to json object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need result like the following json object:

```js
testObj = [{
  test1: "cat",
  category: "Animal"
}, {
  test2: "parrot",
  category: "Bird"
}, {
  test3: "Dog",
  category: "Animal"
}]
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It's unclear at the moment. You want to create `testObj` from what?

Answer (score -1):

Create an object than push to your testObj array.
Like this

```
obj = { test1: "cat",category: "Animal"};
testObj.push(obj);
```

This will create you required dynamic JSON array.